# Attach blender hair to mixamo fbx character

Tags: animation

I created a character in Fuse, imported them in Mixamo for animation and finally imported it back in blender. Thing is, I made hair with blender seperately but cant attach it to the movements nor the head of my character.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Select the hair first then the armature while holding shift. Then press ctrl+p and select "with automatic weights". After all you can correct the result in weight paint mode if it needed.

Comment: Just tried it but it didnt work. :( Hair doesnt move at all.

Comment: Use the weight paint tool or reassign the vertex groups.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or smth? I am a newbie and I dont understand.

Comment: Several times now I tried to attach the hair by selecting it and the armature (complete selection, armature only selection and head-part of armature). With Ctrl+P. I did this with an unanimated character and with one which I got from mixamo directly as an animated one (Dances Samba). But the hair stays still and does not follow my characters head movements. I know theres got to be a way but cant find it. I am sitting on this for days now.. :(

Comment: So I attached the hair, using the vertex assignments and stuff. Thank you so much. Now the hair is at least moving with the head of my character. Only thing that is missing is that the hairs move dynamically... I guess that is achieved with weight painting ?

Comment: How can I weight paint that hair now, is there a decent tutorial on that topic? My hair does not appear the be weight paintable since it is not marked blue from the get go.